# Something is removing tags from posts

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom theme.  I've been fighting with the Editor.  It wants to change the HTML and make my site view different.

I added some text to a post.  HTML.  When I view it, wordpress is removing some `<p>` tags, adding others and removing others making the page become invalid.  Ive never encountered anything like this and its ridiculous.  Im looking at the text I submit.  It contains valid, empty tags `<p> </p>`.  But when I view the results of the end page it only contains `</p>`.  Not sure why this is happening, more funky behavior.

BTW, now Stack overflow is jumping around my screen.  Complains that a ! is in my title, but when I try to remove it, the entire input VANISHES!

Comment: Something weird is making it impossible for me to edit my questions.  Im running into so many bugs now on thsi.

Comment: I edited your question to make the `<p>` and `</p>` tags visible... Are you already using WP5 with the Gutenberg editor or are you talking about the "classic" editor (TinyMCE)?

Comment: Have you searched and seen posts like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312622/stop-wordpress-from-removing-html-comments-in-content ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use ACF plugin for custom template. You can crate any input field and just point to which page that you want to show the custom filed. It is not very hard and compatible with any WordPress version even WP 5 as well.

[Download ACF plugin here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

[Documentation here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/)